# PHP: Get static method reference

Tags: php, class, reference, static

I want to get the reference of a static method from another static method in same class, but PHP interprets the two lines (see example code below) always as an access to a constant. Is it not possible to get a reference to static methods in PHP?

```
class foo
{
    public static function test()
    {
        self::bar();  // calling (not referencing) works
        $bar_reference = self::bar;  // Error: Undefined class constant 'bar'
    }

    public static function bar()
    {
        echo "hello";
    }
}

foo::test();
$bar_reference = foo::bar;  // Error: Undefined class constant
```

Just to clarify it again: I do NOT want to call the static method - I just want to get a reference to it.

Comment: PHP doesn't have references to identifiers. You can only reference variables. Or use a stringified identifier for callbacks.

Comment: @mario: for all intents and purposes, the stringified identifier really is a reference in PHP,

Comment: If it is not possible, then ok. But I don't understand why this is a reason to down vote my question (or did I asked something the wrong way?)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a [*callable*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) like this:

```
class foo 
{
    public static function test()
    {   
        $bar_reference = array(__CLASS__, 'bar');
        // Call it
        $bar_reference();
    }   

    public static function bar()
    {   
        echo "hello";
    }   
}

foo::test();
$bar_reference = foo::bar();
```

Comment: Ok. What do you want to do with the reference?